# How to only use an exact string as a parameter with sed

Tags: string, shell, sed

I'm trying to get a simple script to read a file named "test1.txt" and check for a string such as foo and replace just that exact string.

test1.txt is as follows:

```
foo = false
barfoo = false
foofoo = false
```

My code is as follows:

```
ChangeSettings(){
if [[ $(grep $1 test1.txt) ]]; then
    sudo sed -i "/$1/c $2" test1.txt
else
    sudo echo >> test1.txt "$2"
fi
}
ChangeSettings foo 'foo = true'
```

What it does is that it searches the file for the first parameter and replaces the entire line with the second parameter. However, this leads to an error where if it finds a string within a larger string, it will replace the entire line.

The output is:

```
foo = true
foo = true
foo = true
```

I would like it to be:

```
foo = true
barfoo = false
foofoo = false
```

I'm still new to bash scripting and I looked for an answer for a while. So my apologies if this is a repeat question.

Comment: Use the `{}` button in the editor with a block selected, or four-space indents, to format multi-line code segments; backtick-based formatting is intended for one line or less.

Comment: BTW, `sed` is a separate program rather than part of the shell, and I don't see how this is a question about bash-the-language as opposed to sed-the-language; as such, this should probably be either clarified or tagged and titled differently.

Answer (score 2):

with word boundary

```
sed 's/\bfoo\b/& = true/' file
```

**UPDATE**

For the new version of the problem, `awk` is a better alternative.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" = "} $1=="foo"{$2="true"}1' file
```

this idiom is to replace values of given key with an exact match.  Assumes there are spaces surrounding equal sign.

Comment: Thank you for asking the question...but it just so happens that it doesn't work for the actual script I was going to use it on because it simply just appends "= true" to the end of the line when I was more or less hoping to replace "= false" with "= true" or if it is set to "= true", keep it that way (it would delete the entire line and add it back in again). Thank you for answering it btw.

Answer (score 0):

```
from='foo';to='foo = true';sed "/^ *$from *=/{s:^.*\$:$to:}"
                                       ^            ^
                                       |____________|___ line begins with "$from"
                                                    |___ replace line with "$to"
```